# From inside a function How can I access a method of a global object

Tags: python, function, methods, paho, global

I have a `Paho-MQTT` client object declared on main context of my python script.

I need to call the `connect` method of this object inside a function but it seems to not work. But if I call the object method from outside a function, the method `connect` is recognized by IDE

Could somebody help with this please?

Example:

```
from paho.mqtt import client as CloudClient

myClient = CloudClient.Client("ClientID", True, None, CloudClient.MQTTv311)

def fn_connec_my_client():
    global myClient
    myClient.connect(bla bla bla)  # this .connect method seems to be not available here

fn_connec_my_client()
```

Comment: Is your code not executing, or is it just because you don't want the IDE warning of "unrecognized method"? You could also pass `MyClient` as an argument to `fn_connec_my_client`.

Comment: Your code is fine, although the `global myClient` isn't really required. There's some other issue. Perhaps the `CloudClient.Client()` call didn't work or doesn't do what you think. Please add the actual error message to you question.

Comment: If I put myClient.connect outside the function, the method works fine but when I put him inside the function, he don't run ( I've put some print()'s to check if the function is called )

Comment: putting as an argument, I receive a TypeError "fn_connec_my_client argument after * must be an iterable, not Client"

Comment: Could someone help please? Thanks a lot!